# to create rows and columns

Tags: java, arrays

I understand that I can create the rows and columns using nested for loops

Comment: I see no arrays here.

Comment: We're not supposed to use arrays, so all I have now is a nested for loop statement for creating the rows and columns of the maze. Then, the user is supposed to be able to navigate through them.

Comment: There are many options here, including (1) a list of lists, and (2) a bunch of objects of your own `Cell` class, with fields for the north, south, east, and west neighbor cells. Given that you are taking a class, your assignment probably restricts you to concepts you already know. So do you know how to use `java.util.List`? Have you made your own classes yet?

Comment: Thank you for your help. We've made classes, but I do not remember hearing about java.util.List. This is our first assignment so it's all a little overwhelming for me. I've heard the term 'objects' but I'm not sure if I should be using them yet--what do you think? It's Week 3 in Intro to Java. sorry if these questions are silly...

Comment: It would help to clarify the question if you give an example of the expected output.

Comment: Procedural generation can give you results without storing.

Comment: It would be a 5 by 5 grid of x's with an O (representing the player) at the top left and an E (representing the exit) at the bottom right. The player is then able to hit their arrow keys to move the P to the exit.

Comment: I'm not allowed to create extra classes/methods other than the main one that the program starts in.

Comment: 5 by 5 grid with no arrays? Are you allowed to use any other data structure in the first place? Do you know how to use linked list?

Comment: @matthew You should show the class given to you and the expected output. Who knows there might already exist a 2D array in the class given by your school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot use array and cannot create any new method. You can do something like this:

**Output:**

```
 O  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  .  E
```

**Codes:**

```
    int playerX=0, playerY=0;  //holds player's location
    int exitX = 4, exitY = 4;  //holds exit's location

    //Print map
    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<5; y++)
            if(x == playerX && y == playerY)
                System.out.print(" O "); //print player location
            else if(x == exitX && y == exitY)
                System.out.print(" E ");
            else    
                System.out.print(" . ");
        System.out.println("");     
    }
    /*
    //Update player's position on movement
    if (movement == DOWN)
        playerY = Math.min(playerY+1 , 5);
    else if (movement == UP)
        playerY = Math.max(playerY-1 , 0);
    else if (movement == LEFT)
        playerX = Math.max(playerX-1 , 0);
    else else if (movement == RIGHT)
        playerX = Math.max(playerY+1 , 5);  
    */
```

You can enclose every thing in a while loop, and repeat the loop so long player's location is not same as exit's location.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is home work I am not going to give an answer but rather a hint.

Draw the 5x5 maze you want on paper or whatever. Now you have 25 points. That is 25 conditions of x,y. That is you can make 25 if else statements. Loop through and test your if else chain for each move and rendering.

Yes that many conditions is tedious but I'm sure the point of the assignment is test your ability to properly construct a chain of conditions (you could also use a switch statement using strings for cords but probably not a good idea).